# Error while setting up a 'structuredQuery' in flutter using firebase

Tags: firebase, rest, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set an 'where' in a StructuredQuery using the REST api to cloud firebase in flutter.

Here is my query to database :

```
String filteredApi =
  "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<proj- 
   id>/databases/(default)/documents/<collection-id>/:runQuery? key=${API_KEY}";
var res = await http.post(filteredApi, headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer ${Utils.loginToken}",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  }, body: {
    "structuredQuery": {
      "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
          "field": {"fieldPath": "name"},
          "op": "EQUAL",
          "value": {"stringValue": "XYZ"}
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Error Message is:
This is my updated error message

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type
'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>' is not a 
 subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

Comment: Isn't there any more stacktrace? It looks like a typing issue on your side. Have you tried casting the json to a string before making the call?

Comment: Lost of thanks @Adjordat  but it  still give me error . I have updated the error  message.

Comment: The error message has changed, have you modified your code? If so, add it to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Ajordat. I had not made any changes in code. But still I have update the code.

Comment: Are you saying that you did not change the code but the error message did?

Comment: Yes @Ajordat. I had Update both code and error message also. I am also very much confused. But later I have test it for 7 to 8 time but now giving me the same error.

Comment: Without changing the source code the error you get shouldn't change, this is indeed an strange error and suggests me that the error may not be in the snippet that you shared. Is there any reason you are using the REST API instead of [Flutter's firestore library](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)? This could effectively eliminate the typing errors (and other ones) on your code.